# Resize (enlarge) an image without resampling (in favor of quality loss)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-quality, pixel-art

How to resize an image or selection without resampling the pixels? I have some pixel art that I want to enlarge without losing the hard, non-anti-aliased, pixel edges. In other words, 1px should become 4px of the same color— fake big pixels. Is there any way to achieve this procedurally?

Example (of what I don't want):

before resize:

[image: before]

after resize:

[image: after]

Open to other tools/methods beyond photoshop, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a selection of algorithms in the Resize/Resample dialog. You want "nearest neighbor".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks usr2564301, when in object scaling mode (Edit > Transform > Scale), an Interpolation drop-down appears along the top toolbar:

[image: interpolation]

Nearest Neighbor is the one that achieves this. I'm using CS6, don't know if this applies to other versions of Photoshop.

Comment: It does apply to all versions of Photoshop