# How to tell Photoshop to treat layer as a Vector graphic?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, smartobject, scale

I have a 48*48 png file that I'm trying to scale up. Even though I converted it to a Smart Object, when I scale it up, Photoshop mixes the color of adjacent pixels to make more pixels for the transformed sized which is not what I want.

Here's a screenshot of the image:
[image: original]

When I'm scaling it, the preview does not show mixed colors:
[image: preview]

But when I hit enter, Photoshop mixes the colors:
[image: result]

Which as you can see looks very blurry. How can I achieve the the second photo?

Basically I want to tell Photoshop to treat the layer as a Vector and not an Image.

Here's the original png file if you want to download:
[image: png file]

Comment: What you look for is a different interpolation method, `Nearest Neighbor`: here's a similar question: [Resize an image without resampling?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107209/resize-enlarge-an-image-without-resampling-in-favor-of-quality-loss). Note that Smart Objects don't show the interpolation dropdown when scaling, to use a different interpolation method with those change the method in Photoshop Preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Win to activate the scaling frame, at the top options bar choose **Nearest Neighbor** and then do the scaling.

[image]

[image]